# React-native Android：Error while updating property 'allowFontScaling' in shadow node of type: RCTText

Tags: react-native

We found a serious problem.
When we loaded two jsbundles at the same time, the following Crash occurred.
I suspect that two threads are contributing to each other's resources.
Because the property's property is random.
The property that is reported.
React-native version: 0.46

```
com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: Error while updating property 'allowFontScaling' in shadow node of type: RCTText
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:113)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:154)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:58)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:298)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:289)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:364)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:374)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:162)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactBaseTextShadowNode.setAllowFontScaling argument 1 has type boolean, got null
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:102)
... 15 more
```

Who has encountered this kind of mistake?

Comment: Who has encountered this kind of mistake?